# How do I use cfqueryparam in ORDER BY to list titles matching "School of " first

Tags: coldfusion, sql-order-by, cfquery

How do I use cfqueryparam in the ORDER BY to have titles matching "School of " listed first and then just list the rest of the titles? Here is my current query:

```
<cfquery name="getblogs" dbType="query">
   SELECT title, id,description,date_registered,public1,uri
   FROM myquery 
where public1<>0
order by title asc
</cfquery>
```

What syntax do I use filter by "School of" titles first and then the rest can be ordered in ASC.

**EDIT:** How do I output specific title based on ID matches? I tried this but get an error.

```
<cfquery name="getschoolblogs" dbType="query">
   SELECT id, title, uri 
   FROM   myquery 
   WHERE  id = 396,378
   ORDER BY title asc
</cfquery>
```

Comment: You can't use `cfqueryparam` in the `order by`, but that doesn't seem to impinge on the problem you're trying to solve.

Answer (score 2):

[QoQ's](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/ColdFusion/9.0/Developing/WSc3ff6d0ea77859461172e0811cbec0e4fd-7ff0.html) are extremely limited. They do not support the operators or functions you would need to alter the natural sort order that way. What you could do is use a `CASE` in your database query to create an additional sort column. Then sort by it in either your database query OR the QoQ.

```
     SELECT CASE WHEN title LIKE 'School of %' THEN 1
                 ELSE 2
            END AS TitleSortValue
            , title id,description,date_registered,public1,uri
     FROM   YourTable
     ORDER BY TitleSortValue, Title ASC
```

Also, you cannot use `cfqueryparam` in an ORDER BY clause. cfqueryparam prevents the input from being *evaluated* as sql. So it can only be used with simple values, not objects (ie table or column names).

> `where id=396,378`

**Edit:** To answer your later question, you can only compare a single value with `=`. Use `IN (...)` to filter on multiple values:

```
   WHERE ID IN  ( <cfqueryparam value="#listOfIDValues#" 
                      cfsqltype="cf_sql_integer"
                      list="true">
                )
```

Comment: I tried adding this and changing YourTable to myquery but it threw my site and error, am i missing something

Comment: (Edit) Um.. like I said, it must be done in your original **database** query. It will _not_ work in a QoQ.

Comment: I apologize, I am not really a database cfml coder, can you explain how i would go about doing this on my original database query, sorry for my ignorance, i mean i do not even know what QoQ stands for

Comment: Sure. If you update the your question with the original database query I can post an example.

Comment: @Alpdog14 QoQ stands for Query of Query. Leigh made that a link for you as well.

Comment: Still not really following, my original database query is in my initial question or are you saying I should modify it using your code and myquery?

Comment: So how about if I just do another cfquery before that finds all records that begin with "School of XXX", output that then do another query that shows all minus that first query, how would I do that?

Comment: Sorry I got called away.  I meant QoQ's (ie in memory queries) need an *existing* query object to work. So somewhere else in your code you are running *another* `cfquery` named "myQuery" first. That is the code we need to see.

Comment: Ok thanks for guiding me, I got it working, I just did an initial cfquery to find the ids i wanted first, outputted them then I did another query that output all the ids but minus the ids i pulled in the first query, overall it works

Comment: (Edit:) Glad you got it working. Two queries works too, though my preference would a single query :) Implementing it is pretty much what I showed above. You just need to add the `CASE WHEN ... END` part to your database query in the right spot.

Answer (score 2):

One of the way s is like this:

```
<cfquery name="getblogs" dbType="query">
   SELECT title, id,description,date_registered,public1,uri,
   CASE left(title, 9) WHEN 'School of' THEN 1 ELSE 2 END as sortIdx
   FROM myquery 
   where public1<>0
   order by sortIdx, title asc
</cfquery>
```

You can do some better variation on the condition, it's just first one that came to mind.

Comment: But you can only do that in a database query. QoQ's do not support `case` or `left`.

Comment: I have tried this but my site just shows and error after I add it, do you know why it would error out after I replace the content with what you put

Comment: QoQ's do not support those functions. They support `upper,lower,cast` and not much else. It has to be done in your database query. See [my response](http://stackoverflow.com/a/13037625/104223) for additional details.

Comment: Yes I didn't notice that you had `dbType="query"` Leigh is correct you can't do this in QoQ, as he suggested you could do this in original query and add another column to sort by

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to be returning a column you don't need but to get the same result just use a case statement in the order by.

```
<cfquery name="getblogs" datasource="dsn">
   SELECT title, id, description, date_registered, public1, uri
   FROM   tbl_blogs
   WHERE  public1<> 0
   ORDER BY CASE left(title, 9) WHEN 'School of' THEN 1 ELSE 2 END,
            title ASC
</cfquery>
```

This will avoid returning data you don't need.

Comment: True. It was not clear whether there was a specific reason for doing a separate (ordered) QoQ. So I left it in the SELECT just in case.